# finding the parity(even or odd) of modulo calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let *a* = *b* mod *m*, where *b* is 2 *n* bits long, and *m* is *n* bits long， *n* maybe large.
How to get the parity of *a* without know a. Because we don't want to know *a*, there maybe a quick algorithm to get the parity of *a*, in the perspective of theory of information.

Similarly, let *a* = *b* * *c* mod *m*, where b and c and m are *n* bits long.
How to get the parity of a without evaluating multiply and modular.

Comment: If $m$ is even, $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. If $m$ is odd, they may not.

Comment: what do you mean by parity? parity as in odd number and even number?

Comment: Yes, odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

You are making an unwarranted assumption that calculating the parity of $a$ must be easier than calculating $a$.  Here is a lower-bound argument which  refutes the premise underlying your question.

Let $m\ge 3$ be any odd number (user296602 has already explained why $m$ even is trivial), and choose $b$ to any long number consisting of digits between $1$ and $8$ such that $b$ is divisible by $m$.

[The existence of arbitrarily large $b$ of this type is a nice exercise but not really critical to this argument since for any given $m$ there are plenty of examples available (in the simplest case where $5 \nmid m$, we may simply take $b$ to be a string of repeating $3$s of an appropriate length, and in the general case we can appeal to an argument similar to [For every positive number $n$, there exists a $n$ digit number having all odd digits and divisible by $5^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850377/for-every-positive-number-n-there-exists-a-n-digit-number-having-all-odd-di).])

Let us add one additional constraint on $m$, that it not be a power of $5$.  If $m = 5^r$ then $b$ mod $m$ can be computed from just the last $r$ digits of $b$, which makes the question moot as it is already easy to compute $a$ exactly.

So far, we know that $a = 0$ so that $a$ is even.  But I claim there is no way for us to compute this without having examined **every** single digit of $b$.  Suppose we neglected to examine any single digit of $b$, say at position $d$.  Then we could replace $b$ by $b'$ where $b$ and $b'$ are identical except at position $d$, and the output of our algorithm would have to be the same.

By our choice of $b$, we may freely add or subtract one from position $d$.  Thus we may take $b' = b \pm 10^k$, where we don't control the value of $k$ (the argument needs to work for arbitrary $k$) but we do control the $\pm$ sign.

Since $m$ is divisible by at least one prime other than $2$ or $5$, $10^k$ is not divisible by $m$, so it has a non-zero residue $c$ mod $m$.

If $c$ is odd, then $b' = b + 10^k$ has an *odd* residue mod $m$, which means we *must* examine that particular digit of $b$ in order to know the parity of $a$.

If $c$ is even, then we take the opposite sign: $b' = b - 10^k$ has residue $m-c$ mod $m$, which is odd.  And again this proves we must examine that digit of $b$ in order to know the parity of $a$.

We conclude that it is impossible to know the parity of $a$ without at least checking every digit of $b$, and in roughly that same amount of time we could have computed $a$ itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's very useful.

Comment: I think it's inevitable to check every digit of b too. 
But I'm not sure about your last sentence. After all, modulo calculation is hard. Even the fast reduction algorithms such as barrett or montgomery are slow, asking for at least two multiplies (equal or wider than m), without regarding for some precomputing. But checking the digits of b maybe much easier or harder than multiply. So I guess that calculating the parity of a maybe easier than calculating a，because I only need a little information of a.
Looking forward to your idea.
Thanks again!

Comment: @xikezn I suppose I had in mind a relatively small value of $m$ compared to $b$.  Computing $b$ mod $m$ just in the naive way requires length($b$) multiplications of one number of width $m$ and another of fixed size.  It was not at all obvious from the question that you considered $m$ to be large enough that such operations are expensive: a more naive writer might have asked the same question hoping there was an $O(1)$ algorithm for extracting one bit :).

Comment: I'm sorry that my question was not rigorous and confused you. Supposing m is a n bits number and b is a 2n bits number, the computational complexity of the naive way is O(n^2). I hope the algorithm is about O(n^k), where k is less than 2.
Thanks very much.