# Show that there is a unique $k$ such that $1\le k\le5$ and $5\mid b+2^nk$ for any positive integers $b$ and $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

EDIT: Show that for any positive integers $b$ and $n$, there is an integer $k$ such that $1\le k\le5$ and $5\mid b+2^nk$

I came across this problem while trying to understand the answer to the following question:
[For every positive number $n$, there exists a $n$ digit number having all odd digits and divisible by $5^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850377/for-every-positive-number-n-there-exists-a-n-digit-number-having-all-odd-di?rq=1)

I tried plugging in values of $b$ and $n$, and indeed there is always a $k$ that makes $b+2^nk$ divisible by 5. So far, I know that if I let:

$k\equiv -3^nb\pmod5$.

then I get $6^nb\equiv b\pmod5$. I also know that $6^n\equiv n\pmod5$.
How to get to $5\mid b+2^nk$ from there?

Comment: What?  That's nonsense.  If $5|b + 2^nk$ then $5 \not \mid (b+1) + 2^nk$ so obviously there is no such number.

Comment: Sorry, I worded the question badly. $k$ does not stay the same when $b$ and $n$ are changed. So for one choice of $b$ and $n$, there is one $k$ that meets the condition, and then for another choice of $b$ and $n$, another $k$ from 1 to 5 inclusive should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gcd(2,5) = 1$ so $2^n \not \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  but $2^n\equiv m \mod 5$ for some distinct $1,2,3,4$ (all numbers that are no multiples of $5$ are.)

Now $5$ is prime so the non-zero value of $\mathbb Z_5$  is a field under modulo addition and mulitiplication.  That is to so for any value $m\not \equiv 0 \mod 5$ we can find an value, we'll denote as $m^{-1}$ where $m*m^{-1}  \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

Specifically if $m\equiv 1,2,3,4 \mod 5$ then $m^{-1}\equiv 1,3,2,4 \mod 5$ respectively.

So for $b \equiv 0,1,2,3,4 \mod 5$ then there is $(-b) \equiv 0,4,3,2,1 \mod 5$ so that $b + (-b) \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

So we have $2^n \equiv m \not \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  That there is a $m^{-1}$ so the $m*m^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and we know there is an $-n$ so that $b + (-b) \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

So just let $k \equiv (-b)*m^{-1} \mod 5$.

That's all there is to it.

$b + 2^n*k \equiv  b + m*k \equiv b + m*m^{-1}(-b) \equiv b - b \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

Remains to argue $k$ is unique.

that's the beauty of fields.  $b + m*k = 0$ has a unique solution $k = -b*m^{-1}$.