# Prove that for any positive integer $n$ there exists an $n$-digit number that is divisible by $5^{n}$ and contains only the digits $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Prove that for any positive integer $n$ there exists an $n$-digit number that is divisible by $5^{n}$ and contains only the digits $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

My attempted solution:

Proof by induction.

The base case: $n=1$.

$m=5$ is divisible by $5^{1}$ and contains only the digits $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

The induction hypothesis: there exists an n-digit number $m=5^{n}k$ that is divisible by $5^{n}$ contains only the digits $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

The induction step: the $(n+1)$-digit number will be one of the following,

$5*10^{n} + m = 5^{n}(5*2^{n}+k)$

$6*10^{n} + m = 5^{n}(6*2^{n}+k)$

$7*10^{n} + m = 5^{n}(7*2^{n}+k)$

$8*10^{n} + m = 5^{n}(8*2^{n}+k)$

$9*10^{n} + m = 5^{n}(9*2^{n}+k)$

Then, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know I have to apply my number theory knowledge here. But not sure how.

Comment: Related? [For every positive number $n$, there exists a $n$ digit number having all odd digits and divisible by $5^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/850377/89922)

Comment: @peterwhy I guess mine is the special case of that, but I would like to receive answers on this specific problem.

Comment: By the similar logic as in the linked question, for the induction step here, pick the most significant digit equivalent to $-k\left(2^n\right)^{-1} \pmod 5$ and among $5,6,7,8,9$.

Comment: The same method in the dupe works here, except choose $k$ to be one of your sought digits.